# Trying to get the next post within the main loop (ie. two posts per iteration)

Tags: wordpress

This is what my code looks like:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'home_templates_list', 'posts_per_page' => 20, 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'DESC' ) ); ?>
<?php $isFirstTemplate = true; ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="item<?php if($isFirstTemplate) { echo ' active'; $isFirstTemplate = false; } ?>">
        <?php $templateLink = get_the_excerpt(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><a href="<?php echo empty($templateLink) ? '#' : $templateLink;?>"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>" /></a></div>

        <?php if ($loop->current_post + 1 < $loop->post_count) { ?>
            <?php $loop->next_post(); ?>
            <?php $templateLink = get_the_excerpt(); ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6"><a href="<?php echo empty($templateLink) ? '#' : $templateLink;?>"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>" /></a></div>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I am trying to make the main loop to be incremented by two. ie, two posts per iteration. Tried using the `next_post()` method but it appears to be that the `get_the_excerpt()` and `$post->ID` are still pointing to the first post!

Is there a better way for this? Thank you

---

**EDIT**

What I want to do is, two items(posts) per loop. Say for example, a simple while loop example of what am trying to achieve would look like this:

```
while(i < 10)
{
  echo a[i]; 
  echo a[i+1]; 

  i=i+2; 
}
```

Like this, I want to print two posts per iteration.

Comment: I don't get you on this. You are getting 20 posts per page, and then....

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I want to do is, two items(posts) per loop. Say for example, a simple while loop example of what am trying to achieve would look like this:
`while(i < 10){ echo a[i]; echo a[i+1]; i=i+2; }`. Like this, I want to use print two posts per iteration. Thank you

Comment: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($loop, 1).'</pre>';` - will let you see what is being returned in the WP_Query class. This will get you to a solution on your own.

Comment: @iambriansreed: Thank you. I found that all the data is being stored in the `$loop->posts` as array of objects. But calling the `$loop->the_post()` seems to be automatically incrementing the counter and loading up the next post. So, the only change that I have done is, replaced the `$loop->next_post();` with `$loop->the_post();`. Like this: http://i.imgur.com/4son1DG.png Looks like it seems to be working. Thank you